# Vuex, vuejs - not binding as expected on select elements options

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

### Vue versions:

```
"vue": "^2.5.17",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",
"vuex": "^3.0.1"
```

### Background:

This is for a game I'm building.
The page is simple with two `<select>` drop down selection elements.
The second `<select>` element's `<options>` are dynamic from an API request, and depend on which  option is being used from first element along with a conditional test using a getter on the Vuex store.

### The Problem

When I toggle the currency type menu, and then toggle it back to the original setting, the second `<select>` is no longer bound to the value it should be as shown in the Vuex store.

The `Price. currency` remains: `"USD"` but when toggled back, **the select menu looses this binding and displays blank**.

```
<label for="currency-type">Choose currency type: </label>
<select id="currency-type" :value="Price.currencyType" @input="setCurrencyType">
  <option 
    v-for="item in Price.availableCurrencyTypes"
    :value="item"
  >{{item}}</option>
</select>


<label for="currency-selection-dynamic">Choose a currency [dynamic]: </label>
<select id="currency-selection-dynamic" :value="Price.currency" @input="setCurrency">
  <option
    v-for="item in this.getAvailableCurrencies"
    :value="item.currency"
  >{{item.currency}}: {{item.label}}</option>
</select>
```

### Desired Outcome:

I want to be able:

- to toggle between the currency types in the first `<select>` and for the value stored in the Vuex store to still be selected when I toggle back.
- to expect it to be binded, as the vuex store still says `Price.currency = "USD"`, and the `<select>` is bound using the `:value` so I believe it should be selecting the `USD` option but its not. So it seems the binding is not being rendered in the browser.

I hope that you can understand this issue. I think it will really be easier for you to look at the repo and run it to see what I am on about here!

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with this for days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to bind to the vuex properties you need a two way computed property like this:

```
<input v-model="message">

computed: {
  message: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.obj.message
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateMessage', value)
    }
  }
}
```

More info here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

Comment: Thanks Imre_G, I couldn't get it working using the first method described in the documentation link you provided. That method was to have (in the vue component) a computed property retrieving the data from the store, then a local method that sent a commit to the stores corresponding mutation function. I couldn't get that to work. Instead when I used the "Two-way Computed Property" as described in the link it worked. Very peculiar...